# What does "<be> open with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, adjectives

In a house description, it said

> "The living room is open with large windows, sliding glass door to outside balcony."

How to understand this sentence, and what does "is open with" here mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence in the example should be read as:

**The living room is open, with large windows and a sliding glass door to an outside balcony.**

Meaning, "The living room is open. It has large windows..."

The words "open" and "with" are part of separate clauses and are not connected. "Open" describes the living room, and "with" introduces the second clause.